# How can I modify or filter this variable in an existing class? (Mai Theme)

Tags: functions, filters, oop

I'm trying to utilize existing post-grid functions to show attachment posts but `$post_status` is hard coded to be either 'publish' or 'private' whereas attachments have a status of `inherit`. I added 'inherit' to their source code to confirm it works but I am trying to achieve this without modifying the source.

There are a couple layers of methods in the Class before it renders so I'm having trouble figuring out how I can filter `$post_status` to 'inherit'.

##### This is what I'm trying to do:

This works when I use `$args` for anything but attachments.

```
function my_attachment_grid() {
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
    ];
    do_grid( 'post', $args );
}
```

##### This is what I'm working with:

Here is the function (outside of Class). If I `var_dump($grid)` before `$grid->render()`, I can see all the default $args but $query_args is empty. `$post_status` is not listed here.

```
function do_grid( $type, $args = [] ) {
    $args = array_merge( [ 'type' => $type ], $args );
    $grid = new Mai_Grid( $args );
    $grid->render();
}
```

##### The Class itself:

Notice `get_post_query_args()` declares `$post_status` as 'publish', assigns it to `$query_args`, then `apply_filters()`. But as mentioned above, `$query_args` is protected and empty in a new Object.

I believe I should be able `add_filter()` but I'm not sure if I'm calling it correctly or if it's even possible since it's hard coded within and not showing within the default args.

```
class Grid {
    // all protected 
    public function __construct( $args ) {
        $args['context']  = 'block'; // Required for Mai_Entry.
        $this->type       = isset( $args['type'] ) ? $args['type'] : 'post';
        $this->defaults   = $this->get_defaults();
        $this->args       = $this->get_sanitized_args( $args );
        $this->query_args = [];
    }

    public function render() {
        $this->query = $this->get_query();
        // ...
        do_entries_open( $this->args ); // Open.
        $this->do_grid_entries(); // Entries.
        do_entries_close( $this->args ); // Close.
    }

    public function get_query() { // modify if post query or term query
        $this->query_args = $this->get_post_query_args();
        return $query;
    }

    public function get_post_query_args() {
        $post_status = 'publish';
        $query_args = [
            'post_status' => $post_status,
            //..
        ]
        // ...
        return apply_filters( 'post_grid_query_args', $query_args, $this->args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it takes asking a question to find out the answer.

```
function my_attachment_grid() {
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    ];
    add_filter( 'post_query_args', 'my_filter', 10, 1 );
    do_grid( 'post', $args );
}

function my_filter( $args ) {
    
    $defaults = ['post_status'=>'inherit'];
    $args = array_merge( $args, $defaults );

    return $args;
}
```